# How do I play two SoundEffectInstance variables in a row?

Tags: audio, xna, playback, effect

I'm making a game in XNA 4.0 and I want two sound effects to play in a row to form a sentence (e.g. The first sound effect may say "You have selected" while the second says "Game number 1"). The current code that I'm using makes the two sound effects play at the same time. How can I make them play one after the other?

```
soundEffectOne.Play();
soundEffectTwo.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling both in the same update, then it makes sense that they'd both play at once.

You'll need to add in some functionality to check that the first sound effect has finished playing and then call the second effect.